# Ionic list views inside slide

Tags: javascript, css, list, scroll, ionic-framework

I have ionic `ion-slide-box` and that contains 3 slides and each slide contains `ion-list` (table view) , the problem is each list items contains different amounts of items so each list views height will be different from other, but if you scroll shortest list item it scrolls empty contents because its sibling list item is taller than this. 
[please check this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhSe6.png).

How can i prevent this behaviour.

```
<ion-slide-box>
  <ion-slide>
    <ion-list>
      // LIST A: this list view contains ~1000 items so this is the talles 
    </ion-list>
  </<ion-slide>
  <ion-slide>
    <ion-list>
      // LIST B: this list view contains ~5 items so this is the shortest 
    </ion-list>
  </<ion-slide>
  <ion-slide>
    <ion-list>
      // LIST B: this list view contains ~400 items.
    </ion-list>
  </<ion-slide>
</ion-slide-box>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `</ion-slide-box>` try using ionic tab view.